# Argentinian wants to work for company in Europe and receive transfers to bank in the US, how to pay tax?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, non-resident, working-abroad

I'm from Argentina, I live in Argentina, and I worked in the US for three months. I have an account in Bank of America. I'm about to start working as a freelancer for a company in Germany and I want to get the money transferred to my Bank of America account. What taxes should I pay for this in the US and how do I do that?

Comment: In my required anti corruption training, what you are proposing to do (earn money in one country and have it deposited in a 3rd country) is considered a red flag for doing business with someone. I would think carefully about this.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not live in the U.S. and are not a U.S. citizen, you can transfer the money into the U.S. without paying any U.S. tax. You only have to pay U.S. income tax if you are a U.S. resident or citizen. I am not an accountant, so please double check this information!